# Unable to Retrieve Profile Metadata in VS Code due to Special Characters

Tags: metadata, vs-code, custom-profile

I am attempting to pull Salesforce Profile metadata into Visual Studio Code and the process is failing with the following error:
`Metadata API request failed: Component conversion failed: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\force-app\main\default\profiles\*Custom%3A Service %28Candidate%29.profile-meta.xml'`

I can manually pull certain profiles, but not others; the common denominator seems to be special characters in the Profile label/name. e.g. for the above error, the profile in question has the name `*Custom: Service (Candidate)`.

I am hesitant to modify the name of the profile due to legacy technical debt where automation leveraged the name rather than the ProfileID. Is there any other way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project's package.xml file includes the following code:

```
<types>
<members>ProfileName</members>
<name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

Try to retrieve it from package.xml file only.

Comment: This is in my package.xml file and retrieving from the package file is what is generating the above error.